# Antiderivative of $f(x)=2x$ using Riemann sums

Tags: integration, summation, riemann-sum

I need to calculate the antiderivative of $f(x)=2x$ using only Riemann sums.

I tried to create the sums so that the limit when $n$ tends to $\infty$ of:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{i=1}^nf(\xi_i^*)\Delta x$$

Will give me the answer, but I can't get rid of the variables $b$ and $a$ which exist in $Δx$ and $\xi_i^*$.

After solving I concluded that the limit is equal to $(b^2-a^2)$ but I doubt that this is the correct answer.

EDIT:
Apparently this is the correct answer, so I should change the question to how $b^2-a^2$ is equivalent to the antiderivative $x^2$

I know it may seem trivial, but I would appreciate a complete understanding of the solution

EDIT#2:
Just writing my solution, for anyone who wonders how to get there

$$\Delta x=\frac{b-a}{n}$$
$$\xi_i^* =a+\frac{(b-a)i}{n}$$
$$f(\xi_i^*)=2a+\frac{2(b-a)i}{n}$$
So
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{i=1}^nf(\xi_i^*)\Delta x= \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\left[\left(2a+\frac{2(b-a)i}{n}\right)\frac{b-a}{n}\right]=$$ then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{2ab-2a^2}{n}+\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{2(b-a)^2i}{n^2}=$$
$$2ab-2a^2 +\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2(b-a)^2}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n i=$$
$$2ab-2a^2 +\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2(b-a)^2}{n^2}\frac{n(n+1)}{2} = b^2-a^2$$

Comment: What is the motivation behind this exercise in self-flagellation?

Comment: $b^2-a^2$ is the correct answer as you computed

Comment: But the antiderivative is $x^2$ how can i connect my answer to it?

Comment: Hem, don't you see a connection between $x^2$ and $b^2-a^2$ ???

Comment: You may want to brush up upon the difference between antiderivative, definite integral, and indefinite integral. An antiderivative for $f(x) = 2x$ is $F(x) = x^2$, because $F'(x)= f(x)$. Also $F(x) + c$ for any constant $c$ is also an antiderivative. You do not compute antiderivatives using Riemann sums; you compute definite integrals using Riemann sums for a little while until you learn the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: Thank you for explaining, the question states the need of an antiderivative that's why i thought that there ought to be something more in my answer, but now it's all clear

Comment: "*The*" (general) antiderivative or "*an*" antiderivative of $f$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Riemann sums compute definite integrals.  You have asked for an antiderivative, an indefinite integral, so there is more to this than just computing the sum.  The [fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus) tells us two things.  The second is that for an integrable function $f$, having antiderivative $F$, $$\int_a^b f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x = F(b) - F(a)  \text{.}$$  Note that a given $f$ has infinitely many choices of $F$, all of which work.  (The theorem is actually a little more specific about intervals of definition.  All the functions we will encounter are sufficiently well behaved on the entire real line, so I have suppressed these details.)

You seem to have found that the definite integral $$\int_a^b 2x \,\mathrm{d}x = b^2 - a^2  \text{.}$$  Note that this is a function of $b$ minus a function of $a$ and both these functions are the "square my input" function, $F(x) = x^2$.  So by comparing terms in this particular definite integral with the result in the fundamental theorem, we find an antiderivative.  Since we have used a non-reductive step, we should check that our result is valid: $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} x^2 = 2x$, as desired.

But can we be a little more rigorous?  Yes.  The first part of the fundamental theorem tells us $$ F(x) = \int_a^x f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x  \text{.}$$  (The notation here is awful.  We have used "$x$" in both a bound and an unbound context.  To not write intentionally ambiguous expressions, we should write instead $ F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) \,\mathrm{d}t $.  But more than a century of convention of misusing $x$ in both places means you should get used to seeing and parsing such expressions.)  But we've already done this calculation.  We were just unfortunate in calling the variable $x$ by the name "$b$" previously.  That is, $$F(x) = \int_a^x 2t \,\mathrm{d}t = x^2 - a^2  \text{.}$$  Note that we have recovered the $x^2$ as above, but have an additional "${}-a^2$".  But $a$ is some constant.  If we had chosen any other $a$, this would only translate the graph of $F$ vertically, which would change its derivative, $f$, not at all.  So we are free to make any choice of $a$ and we will get one of the many antiderivatives of $f$.  We could just as easily have written $F(x) = x^2 + C$ for $C = -a^2$.  While $C = -a^2$ is always non-positive for real $a$, the expression $x^2 + C$ is a valid antiderivative of $f$ for any choice of $C$ from the reals.  Consequently, a more general antiderivative of $f$ is the function $x^2 + C$.

Answer (score 3):

In general, if $F(x) = \int_0^x f(u)du$ then

$$\int_a^b f(u) du = F(b)-F(a).$$

---

In your case, you know that the indefinite integral of $2x$ is $x^2$:

$$F(x) = \int_0^x f(u) \, du\qquad\qquad \text{with } F(x)=x^2, \;\;f(u) = 2u$$

When you compute the Riemann sum of $f(u)$ between limit values $u=a$ and $u=b$, you find that the result is $b^2-a^2$. That's the definite integral $F(b)-F(a) = \int_a^b f(u)\,du$, exactly as you were hoping to find.